# Connecting bluetooth device using c programming

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to convert a python code used to connect bluetooth device to Raspberry pi to C code. Is it possible?? Is there a way to connect a bluetooth device to raspberry pi using c programming.
The code is given below:

```
import pygatt
from binascii import hexlify
import time
adapter = pygatt.GATTToolBackend()

def handle_data(handle, value):
    """
    handle -- integer, characteristic read handle the data was received on
    value -- bytearray, the data returned in the notification
    """
    print("Received data: %s" % hexlify(value))

try:
    adapter.start()
    device = adapter.connect('AC:23:3F:AA:36:7C')

    device.subscribe("7f280002-8204-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e",
                     callback=handle_data)

    # The subscription runs on a background thread. You must stop this main
    # thread from exiting, otherwise you will not receive any messages, and
    # the program will exit. Sleeping in a while loop like this is a simple
    # solution that won't eat up unnecessary CPU, but there are many other
    # ways to handle this in more complicated program. Multi-threaded
    # programming is outside the scope of this README.
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
finally:
    adapter.stop()
```

Comment: you can always use Cython to generate a .c file from python code, but actual porting would be much more like writing it from scratch

Comment: Yes, you can find out how pygatt works and use that. Here: https://github.com/peplin/pygatt/blob/master/pygatt/backends/gatttool/gatttool.py we can see it's running the `gatttool` command from bluez. And the code for gatttool is here: https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/attrib/gatttool.c and the `interactive` function:  https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/bc704506e69ae30b0770aac32504e89cf2dc9ddf/attrib/interactive.c

Comment: pygatt seems to rely on [gattlib](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib) and what you want to do looks like one of the example: [notification.c](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/blob/master/examples/notification/notification.c)

Answer (score 1):

Two choices that I know of: https://github.com/petzval/btferret and
https://github.com/weliem/bluez_inc. This is equivalent btferret code.

```
 

    /********* DEVICES.TXT file ************

DEVICE = My Pi         TYPE=mesh node=1  ADDRESS = B8:27:EB:F1:50:C3
DEVICE = LE device     TYPE=LE      NODE=7   ADDRESS = AC:23:3F:AA:36:7C                                      

*******************************************/



/******** C file *****************/
  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "btlib.h"


int callback(int clientnode,int cticn,unsigned char *dat,int len);

int main()
  {
  int cticn;
  
  if(init_blue("devices.txt") == 0)
    return(0);

   // connect to LE device, node 7
     
  connect_node(7,CHANNEL_LE,0);
  find_ctics(7);
  cticn = find_ctic_index(7,UUID_16,strtohex("7f280002-8204-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e",NULL));  
  notify_ctic(7,cticn,NOTIFY_ENABLE,callback);
  read_notify(10000);  // read for 10s
          
  close_all();
  
  return(0);
  }


int callback(int clientnode,int cticn,unsigned char *dat,int len)
  {
  int n;
  
  printf("Notify =");
  for(n = 0 ; n < len ; ++n)
    printf(" %02X",dat[n]);
  printf("\n");
  return(SERVER_CONTINUE);
  }
```